# How can I optimize a query with derived tables?

Tags: mysql

The query below is part of a stored procedure. I think if I can figure out how to fix the below query I can apply those fixes to the rest of my stored procedure.

```
set @startDate = '2020-12-01';
set @endDate = '2020-12-31';

select  cast(x.Year as char),
        cast(x.Original as char),
        cast(x.Beginning as char),
        cast(x.Additions as char),
        cast(x.Collections as char),
        cast(x.Ending as char) 
from(   select  b.Year,     
                format(case when d.Year is not null then d.County when org.year is not null then ifnull(org.amt,0) else 0 end,2) Original ,
                format(case when b.year = (select collectoryear -1 from Entity) then 0 else beg.amt end,2) Beginning,
                format(case when b.year >= (select collectoryear -1 from Entity) then ifnull(org.amt,0) else 0 end,2) Additions, 
                format(case when b.year = (select collectoryear -1 from Entity) then 0 else beg.amt end + case when b.year >= (select collectoryear -1 from Entity) then ifnull(org.amt,0) else 0 end - ending.amt ,2) Collections,
                format(ending.amt,2) Ending
        from Bill b 
        left join DOriginal d on d.year = b.year 
        join (select b.year, sum(bli.amount) amt from Bill b join BillItem bli on bli.bill_id = b.id where  bli.payment = 0 and bli.refund = 0 and bli.adjust = 0 and bli.type = 5 group by b.year ) org on org.year = b.year
        join (select b.year, sum(bli.amount) amt from Bill b join BillItem bli on bli.bill_id = b.id where dateApplied < @startDate and bli.type = 5 group by b.year ) beg on beg.year = b.year
        join (select b.year, sum(bli.amount) amt from Bill b join BillItem bli on bli.bill_id = b.id where dateApplied <= concat(@endDate,' 24:59:59') and bli.type = 5 group by b.year ) ending on ending.year = b.year
        where b.year > (select collectorYear -11 from Entity) 
        and b.year < (select collectorYear from Entity) 
        group by b.year
        order by Year desc 
        ) x;
```

I have attempted to simplify this query. I didn't want to break it down too much for fear of taking something important out. The referenced tables are all indexed. This query is currently taking 13 seconds to run as is.

When I run `explain extended` it shows me what I believe to be the problem. The table `<derived2>` is searching 207 million rows. What can I do to improve that?

```
+---+-----------+-----------+-----+--------------------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|id |select_type| table     |type | possible_keys                  |key        |key_len |ref        |rows     |filtered |Extra                                         |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----+--------------------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|1  |PRIMARY    |<derived2> |ALL  |                                |           |        |           |207501000| 100.00  |Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort  |
|13 |SUBQUERY   |Entities   |ALL  |                                |           |        |           |1        | 100.00  |                                              |
|12 |SUBQUERY   |Entities   |ALL  |                                |           |        |           |1        | 100.00  |                                              |
|2  |DERIVED    |b          |range| billId,year year               |           |4       |           |207499   | 100.00  |Using where; Using index                      |
|2  |DERIVED    |dup        |ALL  | Year                           |           |        |           |1        | 100.00  |Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1)|
|2  |DERIVED    |<derived7> |ref  | <auto_key0>                    |<auto_key0>|4       |pack.b.year|10       | 100.00  |                                              |
|2  |DERIVED    |<derived8> |ref  | <auto_key0>                    |<auto_key0>|4       |pack.b.year|10       | 100.00  |                                              |
|2  |DERIVED    |<derived9> |ref  | <auto_key0>                    |<auto_key0>|4       |pack.b.year|10       | 100.00  |                                              |
|11 |SUBQUERY   |Entities   |ALL  |                                |           |1       |           |         | 100.00  |                                              |
|10 |SUBQUERY   |Entities   |ALL  |                                |           |1       |           |         | 100.00  |                                              |
|9  |DERIVED    |b          |index| PRIMARY,billId,year year       |           |4       |           |414998   | 100.00  |Using index                                   |
|9  |DERIVED    |bli        |ref  | FKF4,type,dateApplied          |FKF4       |9       |pack.b.id  |3        | 100.00  |Using where                                   |
|8  |DERIVED    |b          |index| PRIMARY,billId,year year       |4          |414998  |           |         | 100.00  |Using index                                   |
|8  |DERIVED    |bli        |ref  | FKF4,type,dateApplied          |FKF4       |9       |pack.b.id  |3        | 100.00  |Using where                                   |
|7  |DERIVED    |b          |index| PRIMARY,billId,year year       |4          |414998  |           |         | 100.00  |Using index                                   |
|7  |DERIVED    |bli        |ref  | FKF4,payment,type,refund,adjust|FKF4       |9       |pack.b.id  |3        | 100.00  |Using where                                   |
|6  |SUBQUERY   |Entities   |ALL  |                                |           |1       |           |         | 100.00  |                                              |
|5  |SUBQUERY   |Entities   |ALL  |                                |           |1       |           |         | 100.00  |                                              |
|4  |SUBQUERY   |Entities   |ALL  |                                |           |1       |           |         | 100.00  |                                              |
|3  |SUBQUERY   |Entities   |ALL  |                                |           |1       |           |         | 100.00  |                                              |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----+--------------------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Edit: Work in Progess

````
select b.year, d.Year dYear, d.County, e.collectoryear, sum(bli.amount) amt
from
Bill b 
join Entity e
join BillItem bli on bli.bill_id = b.id
left join DOriginal d on d.year = b.year 
where b.year > (e.collectoryear -11) ```
````

Comment: Do not use subquery, cast immediately.

Comment: And the subquery itself looks like excess... I'd recommend you to try to recreate it from the beginning without subqueries usage.

Comment: How would you change it to avoid the subquery?

Comment: I'd recommend you to create new question. Describe the task itself (not your attempt to solve it), create sample fiddle, show desired output for it, add detailed explanations.

Comment: You're right, but the problem is that I barely know what I'm doing. I am trying to work with queries that are beyond what I could write myself.

Comment: So see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, replace the 6 subqueries that reach for `Entity`.`collectoryear` with a `JOIN` to get it once.

`JOIN` to `bill` and `billitem` only once, then use `CASE` to split the data into 3 choices.

What version are you using?  In the past, it seems that the Optimizer failed to do any sensible optimizations with @variables.  A simple alternative is to use a `JOIN` such as

```
 JOIN ( SELECT '2020-12-01' AS startDate,
               '2020-12-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH AS endDate ) AS dates
```

and then change `<= concat(@endDate,' 24:59:59')` into `< dates.endDate`

I would help you with indexes, but first I need to see what columns (eg dateApplied) is in which table.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables.  (That may lead to getting rid of some of the `CASTs`.)

Tentatively, I recommend `INDEX(type, dateApplied)`.

Another tip:

```
            where  b.year > 
            (
                SELECT  collectorYear -11
                    from  Entity
            )
              and  b.year < 
            (
                SELECT  collectorYear
                    from  Entity
            )
```

-->

```
JOIN ( SELECT collectorYear FROM Entity ) AS e
WHERE b.year > e.collectorYear - 11
  AND b.year < e.collectorYear
```

Comment: I'm using v6.3.10

Comment: I have replaced the 6 ```Entity.collectyear``` with a join, which has helped. When you suggest that I write 3 case statements, can you explain that more? I really appreciate it

Comment: I've edited my post to show what I have so far. I think I need the cast in the where clause, but the ``` if not null ``` in the Original is throwing me off.

Comment: 6.3.10 is not a MySQL version.  What does `SELECT @@version;` give you?

Comment: @EthanGraybeal - I added Another tip.

Comment: You're right. My version is actually 5.1.66-community-log